# Asp.Net webforms and Asp.Net MVC together deployment issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, deployment, iis-7, webforms

I am trying to combine Asp.Net Webforms and Asp.Net MVC together for hybrid application, as per our requirement. I am referring the hanselman's [article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx) for this. It is working fine while running from Visual Studio. But when I have deployed over IIS7, it is giving issue when I tried to visit page which is there, developed using MVC.

It is giving 500 internal server error. And when I try to debug the deployed site it is not even hitting the controller but directly giving error.

I am unable to found the issue and also unable to run page developed using MVC.

Please let me know if any further details needed.

Attaching image here. [image]

Comment: Did you look at the EventLog? Also try disabling errors `<customErrors mode="Off" />` to see if you won't get an YSOD.

Comment: I have tried that. But it is showing error. I am editing my question and putting image too. Hope that will help. Thanks for the quick comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the issue. In deployment dll's are not copied perfectly. So, I updated Entity Framework, clear everything and redeploy it again. It works.

Thanks.